# Starting issue 1996 Suzuki Intruder 1400

Tags: suzuki

I'm new to the bike and new to motorcycles. I bought this bike used, and in the middle of winter so I wasn't able to test ride it. I was able to start it there and see it run. When I got it home I put it on the trickle charger, once it said the battery was 80 percenter my impatience kicked in and I tried to start it-it cranked but wouldn't start. I let it charge up all the way, went to start it and now it just clicks and the "brake" and "neutral" display on the cluster disappear. If I tinker around with it I can usually get the cluster to come back but it still just clicks and won't start. Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like you've got a battery problem ... also, as far as starting it when you can crank it, make sure the fuel petcock is turned to the on position ... also ensure there's fuel in the tank.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I pulled the battery and had it tested-thats good. I did a little more digging, I think I have a bad neutral safety switch. The current one looks like a rock maybe kicked up and smashed it pretty good. The bike just doesn't know it's in neutral and won't allow it to try and start. Anyone ever bypass the neutral switch just to test before ordering a new one?